# Determining if FireBase ChildEventListener made all its work before proceeding Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote a class which receives data from Firebase and puts it into sharedPreferences. But sometimes it is null and sometimes I get the correct data. My code is in below.

```
private void userLogin() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            progressDialog.show();
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                           success=task.isSuccessful();
                            DatabaseReference userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
                            userReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        try {
                                            User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                            if (user.getEmail().equals(email.getText().toString())) {
                                                username= user.getUsername();


                                                key=dataSnapshot.getKey()+"/"+postSnapshot.getKey();

                                            }
                                        }catch(Exception e){

                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                            CountDownTimer cd= new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Log.d("FRIEND", "sendNewFriendRequest: "+username + " bu");

                                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

                                        sharedPreferences.edit()
                                                .putString("username",username)



                                                .commit();
                                    }

                                    if (success) {
                                        Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu.class);
                                        startActivity(i1);
                                    }

                                }
                            }.start();

                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

So I search in FirebaseDB to find an element with the email I want and get its username. Then I try to put this username to SharedPreferences but it is still null when I put it.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to verify the existence of an email address when a user signs in with Firebase. But what happens if the user is already singed in? You'll get null. So in order solve this problem, take that code out of the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method and verify the existence even if the user is signed in.

Hope it helps.